# Launch the existing website with different Logo, name and URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, url-routing

I'm having an existing website. Now I want to launch this same website with a new name, URL & logo in Canada. The difference would be only URL, name and logo. Rest everything (App, DB, layout, server etc.) will remain same.

**I developed the website in ruby on rails 3.2. What is the BEST way to get this done ?**

if a user comes at www.existing.come will be able to see the existing layout

if a user comes at www.forcanada.com. it will load the same website but different logo n name

Comment: so you want the same app to serve both sites?

Comment: Idk, but maybe you could rewrite the url and add an arg, like `domain.com/a/b` => `domain.com/a/b/?domain=canada` for example, and handle it in the app, it won't appear in the URL, but the app will see it

Comment: if we add a function in application_controller and in before_filter we can get the domain name with request.domian and on the basis of this domain we can take decisions in the code. but is this right way to do ? also, can we do anything at nginx level - or some setting in nginx to auto convert the domain logos or anything better than above mentioned approach ?? not sure at nginx level but if we can do something it would be great! any idea guys ?

Comment: I'd prefer using the before filter method, to keep things separate from the server, in the future if you deploy the app on a new server or decide to add a new domain, you wouldn't need to play with your nginx configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the I18n mechanic for it. Do something like the following code in the controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_locale

  private
  def set_locale
    case request.host.split('.').last
    when 'de'
      I18n.locale = :de
    when 'com'
      I18n.locale = :en
    else
      I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
    end 
  end
end
```

Than use `index.de.html.erb` or `index.en.html.erb` for the different views. You can create your own "language" for each site. `en` and `de` are just examples.

Have a look at 
http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/i18n_mehrsprachige_rails_applikation.html

Comment: I dont want different locales - but rather a new name to existing domain with a bit modifications on the layout like logo, title on the basis of new domain and trying to find out the best way. I was informed that it can be done via nginx but not sure either it is possible or not - just doing google it. any idea about server level configurations